# Creating custom query with Spring Data using @Query

Tags: java, spring

I have a Message entity and an Admin entity.
Message is :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "text")
private String text;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_from")
private Admin idFrom;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_too")
private Admin idToo;
```

Admin is:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
```

How can i create this query:

```
select id_from, text from message
where id_from = from and id_too = too
or id_from = too and id_too = from;
```

using @Query annotation?

Something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.id_from = :from.id and m.id_too = :too.id or m.id_from = :too.id and m.id_too = :from.id")
List<Message> findMessages(@Param("from") Admin from, @Param("too") Admin too);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.idFrom.id = :fromId and m.idToo.id = :tooId or m.idFrom.id = :tooId and m.idToo.id = :fromId")
List<Message> findMessages(@Param("fromId") Long fromId, @Param("tooId") Long tooId);
```

Comment: i did, but i don't have enough rep to change the status